# Stuck on a problem from Chapter 12 of Gamelin's Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be a rational function with an attracting fixed point at $z_0$.
Let $U$ be the connected component of the basin of attraction of $z_0$ containing $z_0$. Suppose there is no critical point
of $f(z)$ in $U$ except for possibly $z_0$.

1. Show that $U$ is simply connected.
2. Show that if $f(z)$ has degree $d \geq 2$, then $U$ is conformally equivalent to the open unit disk, and $f(z)$ has a critical point at $z_0$.

I've been working on this problem from Gamelin for a while now, and I've managed to do part 1. and show that $U$ is conformal to the disc. However, I'm failing to see why there must then be a critical point at $z_0$. Any hints would be much appreciated. Thanks!